# Check checkboxes if item is in DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkbox

**BACKGROUND:** I've been working on an asp.net website (barebones fake Client Management System) with C# code behind file and am building basic forms to insert new data and update existing data in a SQL database.

I have a table (**PatientMedicalHistory**) that contains 30+ checkboxes (not in a list) which are used to determine what "ailments" a patient indicated they had when we first create the new patient record via stored procedure. The data is stored as a combination primary key (**PatientId int + AilmentId int**) to avoid duplication. The potential Ailments are stored in another table (**Ailments**) that holds multiple combinations of **AilmentId int** and **AilmentDescription varchar(50)**

I probably should have used a different schema (bit columns for each ailment in 1 combined table) for this table but doing it this way leaves room for adding new "ailments" in the future.

**PROBLEM:** When using sqlcommand to pull a set of patient records from the PatientMedicalHistroy table based on PatientId I want to iterate through the list of currently selected records and check each corresponding checkbox accordingly.

**CODE:**

```
    pIdstring = ("SELECT ailmentId FROM dbo.PatientMedicalHistory WHERE PatientId = " + pId.ToString());
    cmd = new SqlCommand(pIdstring);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    using (conn)
    {
        using (cmd)
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader drCbox = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(drCbox);
                //Need to check all checkboxes that are contained in this datatable.
            }

        }
    }

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="auto-style93" style="background-image: url('Pictures/Bg_WhiteGrayGradient_Tall.jpg'); background-position: center; border-style: inset; border-width: medium">
    <legend id="MedHistoryLegend" style="background-image: url('Pictures/Bg_WhiteGrayGradient_Tall.jpg'); border-style: inset; border-width: medium; font-family: 'Arial Black';">
        <span class="auto-style194">MEDICAL HISTORY</span><asp:Button ID="EditHistory" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CssClass="auto-style189" Height="16px" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit Personal Information" OnClick="EditHistory_Click" />
        &nbsp;</legend>
        <table class="auto-style84" border="3">
        <tr><td class="auto-style85">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="AnemiaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Anemia</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="EmphysemaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Emphysema</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HypoglycemiaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Hypoglycemia</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ShinglesCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Shingles</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="UTICbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Urinary Tract Infection</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="auto-style86">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ArthritisCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style35" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Arthritis</td>
            <td class="auto-style31">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="EpilepsyCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Epilepsy or Seizures</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="IrregularHBCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Irregular Heartbeat</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SickleCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Sickle Cell Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="JaundiceCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Yellow Jaundice</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr><td class="auto-style86">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="AsthmaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style35" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Asthma</td>
            <td class="auto-style31">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="GlaucomaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Glaucoma</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="KidneyCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Kidney Problems</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SinusCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Sinus Trouble</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="auto-style85">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CancerCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cancer</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HeartAtkCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Heart Attack</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="LeukemiaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Leukemia</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SpinaBifidaCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Spina Bifida</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="auto-style87">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ColdSoreCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style36" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cold Sores/Fever Blisters</td>
            <td class="auto-style33">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HeartMurmurCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style62" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Heart Murmur</td>
            <td class="auto-style65">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="LiverCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style30" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Liver Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style74">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="StomachCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style64" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Stomach/Intestinal Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style77">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr><td class="auto-style88">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HeartDisorderCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style122" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Congenital Heart Disorder</td>
            <td class="auto-style90">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HeartDiseaseCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style122" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Heart Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style90">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="JawPainCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style124" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Pain in Jaw Joints</td>
            <td class="auto-style92">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="StrokeCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style124" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Stroke</td>
            <td class="auto-style92">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="auto-style85">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DiabetesCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Diabetes</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HepACbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Hepatitis A</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ParathyroidCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Parathyroid Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ThyroidCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Thyroid Disease</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="auto-style85">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DigestiveCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Digestive Disorders</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HepBorCCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Hepatitis B or C</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="PsychCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Psychiatric Care</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="TumorCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tumors or Growths</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr><td class="auto-style85">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DrugCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Drug Addiction</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="HBPCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style121" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">High Blood Pressure</td>
            <td class="auto-style39">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RheumatismCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Rheumatism</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="UlcerCbox" runat="server" Text=" " />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style123" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Ulcers</td>
            <td class="auto-style76">
                </td>   
        </tr>                   
        </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What's the mapping from the datatable to the checkboxes? Also I suggest using SqlCommand.Paramaters for hardcoded queries.

Comment: have you thought about creating a stored procedure that can pivot the data?

Comment: Short-term solution, change the ID attribute of your checkbox to include the AilmentID in a predictable pattern like "AilmentCbox_1" "AilmentCbox_2" "AilmentCbox_3" etc. so that you can match the controls against the numeric value.
Long-term solution, add row_number and column_number columns to your ailments table so you generate the checkbox controls from the database dynamically, not hard-coded in your ASPX page.

Comment: I was under the impression that by putting the results of the SELECT into a single column datatable I would be able to then iterate through the datatable and anytime "i" existed in the datatable, check the checkbox with the name (ie chkBox_i where i is the current iteration.)?

Comment: Yes. However, your sample code doesn't have the checkbox in the form chkBox_i, it has it more like an ailment alias ("AnemiaCbox" "EmphysemaCbox" "HypoglycemiaCbox" etc.). Also, "i" needs to be the ailment id, not just row number of the results set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an asp `GridView` control instead of a html table? Then you could set the checkbox state in the `rowDataBound` event handler.

Of course it would open you up to a whole range of potential other issues, (GridViews are a pain to work with!) but might be worth a go.

Comment: I did look at it briefly but wasn't really sure how to implement it properly. :-/

Comment: In that case it might be more hassle than it's worth, if you can get your current code working as required. Should be easy enough to find examples that fit your needs on the internet anyway if you do end up going down that route.